# how to replace specific strings in HTML docs or specific elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, string, replace

How can I parse a html document or just a html element in order to replace all specific strings into other ones ?

In other terms:
- search for all strings #### in element .class
- replace them with $$$$$

I'm using jQuery..

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var str = $('.class').text();
str = str.replace(/####/g, '$$$$$');
$('.class').html(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you replace one class with another

```
$(".foo").addClass("bar").removeClass("foo")
```

or are you looking for a way to replace inside text nodes?

```
$("#something").find("*").andSelf().contents().each(function() {
    if(this.nodeType == 3)
        this.nodeValue = this.nodeValue.split(search).join(replace)
})
```

Comment: I think he wants to replace content text that resides inside element with a specific class (.class)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the string [`replace`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) method of javascript for the actual replacing, and look at the [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) and [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) method of jquery on accessing the contents of a specific element..